# How to check which of two numbers is more "round" looking?

Tags: rounding

I want to write a function that will return the "rounder" looking number given two numbers.

Examples:

```
f(1.0001, 1) = 1
f(250, 251) = 250
f(9.74, 9.75) = 9.75
```

I have an intuitive idea of what is the "rounder" number but I don't know to turn that into code.

Comment: [Obligatory article](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).